# Access objects in C++ by its name

Tags: c++, oop, for-loop

I need to access several objects of a class called TH2D, which is defined by the program ***root*** (https://root.cern.ch/drupal/), with a for loop to use two of its methods.

The name of the objects are in the form run_0, run_1, run_2, etc..

defined like this:

```
TH2F* run_0 = new TH2F( "runID = 0", "projection during the first run",
            COLUMN, -COLUMN_BOUND, COLUMN_BOUND,
            RAW, -RAW_BOUND, RAW_BOUND );
```

inside the for loop for the first object I simply do:

```
int bin = run_0->FindBin(j, k);
double Nphotons = run_0->GetBinContent(bin);
```

What do I need to do to have something like this inside a for loop in c++ automatically changing ***run_0*** to ***run_1*** to ***run_2***, etc...?

1st iteration -

```
int bin = run_0->FindBin(j, k);
double Nphotons = run_0->GetBinContent(bin);
```

2nd iteration -

```
int bin = run_1->FindBin(j, k);
double Nphotons = run_1->GetBinContent(bin);
```

SOLVED WITH:

```
TH2F* run[8];
run[0] = new TH2F( "runID = 0", "projection during the first run",
            COLUMN, -COLUMN_BOUND, COLUMN_BOUND,
            RAW, -RAW_BOUND, RAW_BOUND );

....

for( Int_t id = 0; id != 8; ++id)
{
int bin = run[id]->FindBin(j, k);
double Nphotons = run[id]->GetBinContent(bin);
}
```

Comment: Put pointers to them into an array.  Iterate the array.  Assume run_0, run_1, run_2 etc are either already in a collection or are defined somewhere.

Comment: Do you create these objects in your own code? Then you will want to put them (or pointers to them) directly in a container instead of naming individual objects. If, otoh, the objects are in somebody elses library, you can still store pointers to them in a container if you must traverse them more than once. Iterating/looping over containers is trivial.

Comment: I have created the objects in my code with: 

TH2F* run_0 = new TH2F( "runID = 0, "projection during the first run",
   COLUMN, -COLUMN_BOUND, COLUMN_BOUND,
   RAW, -RAW_BOUND, RAW_BOUND );

for example

Comment: Do you have a good reason for newing these objects?

Comment: the objects are basically an histogram of an image projection and I make new TH2F before, because afterwards I will need to fill it in with the information that I will extract from a file.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the objects are. Do you need to dynamically allocate them with `new`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: For simplicity, I will assume tokens in the form `run_n` are functions, rather than objects. This answer should apply to objects, too.*

The only way to place a number like this in an identifier is by macro expansion:

```
#define run(n) run_##n()
run(0); // Good. Will expand to run_0();
```

Unfortunately, that just doesn't work with iteration:

```
#include <iostream>

void run_0(){std::cout << 0;}
void run_1(){std::cout << 1;}

int main() {
  for (int i=0;i<2;++i) {
    run(i); // Bad. Will expand to run_i() and probably cause a compiler error.
  }
}
```

And then you have the problem that macros don't iterate or have recursion.
If you write this:

```
#define run(start,end) run(start,end-1) run_##end();
```

It will not expand into an infinite recursion, as someone might have guessed.
Instead:

```
run(0,1); // Will expand to...
run(0, 1-1) run_1(); // And stop expanding here.
```

Since no **function** `run()` that takes two arguments exists (Hope it doesn't), it will cause a compiler error.

Your only bet, then, is having a list to all possible functions, and then iterate that:

```
void (*run[10])() = {run_0, run_1, run_2, run_3, run_4, run_5, run_6, run_7, run_8, run_9};

int main() {
  for (int i=0;i<10;++i) {
    run[i](); // Now it works!
  }
}
```

The answer to your question, then, is: No, it's not possible. There are not-so-optimal workarounds, of course, but - in essence - it is not possible to iterate over a group of identifiers by name.

EDIT: Since you are defining the objects, and can afford to change how to define them, this is quite simple:

**P.S.: Since you are "newing" the objects, I'm going to use new. Preferably, you should implement the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and allocate them statically, or use a smart pointer instead.**

```
TH2F* run[10]; // Up to 10 objects. Probably better to use an std::vector instead.
run[0] = new TH2F( "runID = 0", "projection during the first run", COLUMN, -COLUMN_BOUND, COLUMN_BOUND, RAW, -RAW_BOUND, RAW_BOUND );
run[1] = new TH2F( "runID = 1", "projection during the second run", COLUMN, -COLUMN_BOUND, COLUMN_BOUND, RAW, -RAW_BOUND, RAW_BOUND );
```

Then you can iterate this array and do what you need.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I cannot do what I want automatically? P.S. I have edited my question, so I think you can have a better understanding of what I want to do :)

Comment: Yes, that't it. It's not possible, unfortunately. For any solution, you will have to list all objects somewhere. Unless, of course **you** are defining the objects in the form `run_n` and are able to change this to the more iteration friendly `run[n]` (i.e.: An array of runs, instead of several separate ones)

Comment: Ok I think I got it.

I am defining each object like this:

`TH2F* run_0 = new TH2F( "runID = 0", "projection during the first run",
   COLUMN, -COLUMN_BOUND, COLUMN_BOUND,
   RAW, -RAW_BOUND, RAW_BOUND );
 
 TH2F* run_1 = new TH2F( "runID = 1", "projection during the second run",
   COLUMN, -COLUMN_BOUND, COLUMN_BOUND,
   RAW, -RAW_BOUND, RAW_BOUND );`

Comment: how can put that in an array?

Comment: Thank you Cassio! I am feeling like a real noob :) With your sugestion I was able not only to get what I needed , but to reduce my code as well :)

Answer (score -2):

In essence, put them in an array:

```
Thingy * thing1 = new Thingy();
Thingy * thing2 = new Thingy();
std::vector<Thingy *> things;
things.push_back(thing1);
things.push_back(thing2);
for(auto thing : things)
{
    thing->doStuff();
}
```

In reality consider using smart pointers instead so you don't forget to delete them afterwards.

**Edit because people don't like it leaking:**

```
std::shared_ptr<Thingy> thing1(new Thingy);
std::shared_ptr<Thingy> thing2(new Thingy);
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Thingy> > things;
things.push_back(thing1);
things.push_back(thing2);
for(auto thing : things)
{
    thing->doStuff();
}
```

and if you really want:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Thingy> > things;
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    things->push_back(std::make_shared<Thingy>());
}
for(auto & thing : things)
{
    thing->doStuff();
}
```

Comment: I think the question was can you do this without having to manually enumerate the objects. Maybe with the ## operator in a macro or some other way.

Comment: memory leak because I was trying to provide the information the OP needed in the simplest form possible, rather than a complete program

Comment: Why new the objects in the first place? Where does it say OP needs dynamic allocation?

Comment: OP says "TH2F* run_0 = new TH2F" as the way he creates objects, and he isn't really asking for a new way to create them - he is asking how to iterate over them.  I'm trying to answer the question that was asked.